# How to use Lodash in a Laravel 4.2 project

Tags: lodash, vue.js, laravel-4.2

How are you doing?

I am working in a project made in Laravel 4.2 and I am using VueJS to do some stuffs and making my life easier... I would like to know if it's possible to use LODASH library with no compiler service...

`var _ = require('lodash');`

It does no work in my project because does not recognise the "require" action.

How would I do it if it's possible?

Comment: what do you mean by "no compiler service"? if you mean without any babel transform, then just include lodash using `<script>` and you will be able to access `_` automatically

Comment: Oh, it worked, I thought that I needed a compiler service to use lodash library, Thanks!